# how to check symfony requirements via command line on WAMP

Tags: symfony

Requirements for running Symfony2 documentation clearly stating that

> it's also a good idea to check your requirements from the command line
>   via:

```
php app/check.php
```

How can I run this on my WAMP? I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open a command line window, navigate to the root directory of your project and execute

```
php app/check.php
```

If this does not work, check that your php binary is in your `PATH` enviroment variable.

Comment: in command line i used php app/check.php like `"D:\wamp\www\seating\Symfony>php app/check.php"` , but i got error `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: As I said, check that your PHP binary is in your "PATH" environment variable

Comment: thanks it works.. i used `cd D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6`, then `D:\wamp\www\MY_PROJECT_FOLDER\Symfony\app\check.php`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check both on the command line **and** on the web app. Some checking depends on your php.ini and they may be different on command line and on Apache.

For example, on my WAMP setup, I have

- `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.ini` for the command line
- `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini` for apache